# Angular JS ng-value is not updating the ng-model when generating dynamic DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where I generate the html using data I got from the server.

```
<input type="{{controls.type}}" class="form-control input-lg mandatory" id="{{$parent.$parent.$index}}_{{controls.id}}" ng-model="formData[$parent.$parent.$index][controls.id]" ng-value="controls.value" name="control_{{$parent.$parent.$index}}_{{controls.id}}" ng-required="{{controls.mandatory}}" ng-class="{checkbox_item : element.type == 'checkbox'}" autocomplete="off">
```

This is my code where I am using ng-value to autofill the data which I am getting from the server but ng-model is not getting updated.

Can anybody tell me is there any other way for auto filling the data or am I doing something wrong.

As I am new to Angular JS I could not figure it out what is happening

Comment: Can you please print something like this to check if it's update or not? <p>{{ formData[$parent.$parent.$index][controls.id] }}</p>

Comment: I have printed {{formData}} only it is not updating but input is showing the value inside the box